# Which part of the xyzij data is the point cloud?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to graphically show the point cloud data to the user, and I'm wondering what part of the `xyzIj` data is the actual coordinates of the point cloud data. I assume it's `XyzIj.xyz`, but on the developers website, this call is described as  "packed coordinate triplet".
   When I print it out it's just separate point numbers; does that mean it prints out an x point, y point, z point, x point, y point, etc... or am I understanding it wrong?

```
    mPointCount = xyzIj.xyzCount;
    //Is this the coordinate points of the point cloud?
    FloatBuffer newPointCloudPoints = xyzIj.xyz;
    int i = 0;
    //Printing out all the points
    while(newPointCloudPoints.get(i) != 0) {
         Log.i(TAG, "point cloud " + i + " " + newPointCloudPoints.get(i));
         i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each "point" has three entries in the buffer.

The first index of the float buffer is x, second is y, third is z.  The sequence repeats for every point.

```
for (int i = 0; i < xyzIjData.xyzCount; i += 3) {
            float x = xyz.get(i);
            float y = xyz.get(i + 1);
            float z = xyz.get(i + 2);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the code example!! That explained my major question, but I have one more. At that point could I just draw the points, or are those raw data which I would have to do something else to draw the PointCloud?

Comment: If you use the points directly you are working in camera space - to work in world space you need to transform the points by the pose.